# How to change the slider style of audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline using css?

Tags: css, webkit, slider, timeline

We can reset -webkit-slider-thumb to change the style of range type input's slider, but the timeline-slider of  element is not support to change its default(webkit) style.

Answer (score 3):

This baffled me too, but it turns out the selector you need to style is:

```
  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/q9GHA/.

Webkit seems to use an <input type="range"> inside audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline as an interface to the timeline!

Comment: thanks. I tried, but no effect. I want to reset the slider style of webkit's native media controls timeline. I can only find two related properties: -webkit-media-controls-timeline and 
-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container, but that's not what I need:(

Comment: I've updated my answer, apologies, my original answer was not accurate.

Comment: Thanks again. I've done that before, however, it'll bring another question: How to real-time move the range type input's slider using javascript without refreshing page?

Comment: This is a different question related to JS + html5 audio. You should open a new question and tag it with JS to catch the attention of the js folks.